# Select2 doesn't select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I use select2 with AJAX data source. It shows the options, but when I choose one, it doesn't show/select the label. It keeps showing empty or the placeholder.

HTML

```
<input   name="organization" id="organization" placeholder="Organization" />
```

Javascript

```
jQuery('#organization').select2({
            placeholder: 'Select an organization',
            ajax: {
                url: '/organizations.json',
                dataType: 'json',
            }
        });
```

JSON Sample:

```
   {
     "results": 
     [
      {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Test Company",
       "value": 1,
       "title": "Test Company",
       "text": "Test Company",
      },
      {
       "id": 2,
       "name": "ABC Company",
       "value": 2,
       "title": "ABC Company",
       "text": "ABC Company",
      }
     ]
   }
```

Am I missing something to make it work?

Comment: Have you checked the console, to check for errors? Also have you chcked if your path to the json doc is correct.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing in the console.

Comment: Did you set the `value` property correctly ?

Comment: Does the ajax response correspond to the required select2 data format?

Comment: Does select2 work without the ajax?  (give it some temp `<option>`s) - ie  `$("..").select2()`

Comment: If I remove the ajax and use static options, it works.

Comment: Fixed somehow. It works with ajax as well, after I replaced the <input> with <select>